How to combine a full join and a update join with a variable number of columns using data.table
I'd like to combine a full join and a update join with a variable number of columns and havn't found an answer covering this case on stackoverflow.
DT is my initial table:
   key_col value_col_1 value_col_2
    <char>       <int>       <int>
1:       a           1          11
2:       b           2          12
3:       c           3          13
4:       d           4          14
5:       e           5          15

which needs to be updated with the data in updateDT:
   key_col value_col_1 value_col_2 value_col_3
    <char>       <int>       <int>       <int>
1:       d          11          21          31
2:       e          12          22          32
3:       f          13          23          33
4:       g          14          24          34

updateDT may add new rows and columns (variable in number) and always has priority over existing data in DT.
The expected result (resultDT) for the above example is:
   key_col value_col_1 value_col_2 value_col_3
    <char>       <int>       <int>       <int>
1:       a           1          11          NA
2:       b           2          12          NA
3:       c           3          13          NA
4:       d          11          21          31
5:       e          12          22          32
6:       f          13          23          33
7:       g          14          24          34

I can get there with hard coded column names, however, the code is repetitive and I'm struggling with generalizing this approach to handle e.g. a third or fourth value_col in updateDT dynamically:
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(key_col = letters[1:5], value_col_1 = 1:5, value_col_2 = 11:15)
updateDT <- data.table(key_col = letters[4:7], value_col_1 = 11:14, value_col_2 = 21:24, value_col_3 = 31:34)
key_column <- "key_col"
value_columns <- setdiff(c(names(DT), names(updateDT)), key_column)

resultDT <- merge(DT, updateDT, by = "key_col", all = TRUE)
resultDT[, value_col_1 := fifelse(is.na(value_col_1.y), yes = value_col_1.x, no = value_col_1.y)]
resultDT[, value_col_2 := fifelse(is.na(value_col_2.y), yes = value_col_2.x, no = value_col_2.y)]
resultDT[, c("value_col_1.x", "value_col_1.y", "value_col_2.x", "value_col_2.y") := NULL]
print(resultDT)


Edit: accepting ismirsehregal's answer as it is faster - Benchmark:
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  ismirsehregal = {
    resultDT1 <- rbindlist(list(old = DT, new = updateDT), use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE, idcol = "origin")[, key_count := .N, by = key_column]
    resultDT1 <- resultDT1[key_count == 1L | key_count > 1L & origin == 'new'][, c("key_count", "origin") := NULL]
    },
  Wimpel = {
    DT[updateDT, on=.(key_col), (value_columns) := mget(paste0("i.", value_columns))]
    resultDT2 <- rbindlist(list(DT, updateDT[!key_col %in% DT$key_col,]), use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
    }, times = 10L)


Unit: milliseconds
          expr    min     lq    mean median     uq    max neval
 ismirsehregal 1.2166 1.2345 1.33790 1.2933 1.3531 1.8147    10
        Wimpel 3.5286 3.5989 3.85624 3.7680 4.0916 4.5984    10


2. Edit: Example of updateDT not containing all of DTs columns:
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(key_col = letters[1:5], value_col_1 = 1:5, value_col_2 = 11:15)
updateDT <- data.table(key_col = letters[4:7], value_col_2 = 11:14, value_col_3 = 21:24, value_col_4 = 31:34)
key_column <- "key_col"
# value_columns <- setdiff(c(names(DT), names(updateDT)), key_column) # Error: value for ‘i.value_col_1’ not found
value_columns <- setdiff(intersect(names(DT), names(updateDT)), key_column) # does not insert all data from updateDT

DT[updateDT, on=.(key_col), (value_columns) := mget(paste0("i.", value_columns))]
rbindlist(list(DT, updateDT[!key_col %in% DT$key_col,]), use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)


I would consider @Wimpel's answer because: 1) it caters for the case when not all of DT's columns are in updateDT (the accepted answer will turn DT's values to <NA> in the updated rows for those columns), and 2) I guess it might be much more memory-efficient on real data, because it update-joins DT in place, then stacks it with only the distinctive rows of updateDT to create a new object. The other answer creates a very large new object (stacking both tables), then another one consisting of the selected rows only.

Also, if you really do mean that updateDT always contains all of DT's columns (as in the example and the accepted solution), a possibility is the one-liner: rbind(DT[!updateDT, on=.(key_col)], updateDT, use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE).

@Tobo Wimpel's answer does not insert all of updateDT's data when e.g. value_col_1 is not existing in updateDT. Please see my edit. Same result when setting origin == 'old' in my code.

@ismirsehregal Your added version is what I had for the general case, and you're right about Wimpel's answer. A fix/adaptation: key_column <- "key_col", update_cols <- setdiff(names(updateDT), key_column), rbind(DT[updateDT, on=key_column, (update_cols) := mget(paste0("i.", update_cols))], updateDT[!DT, on=key_column], fill=TRUE). This works for distinctive columns in both tables (and makes the key col name a variable) though it still mutates DT as a side-effect of course. So, three answers really. Would be interesting to understand how they perform and why.

You can use rbindlist to achive this:
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(key_col = letters[1:5], value_col_1 = 1:5, value_col_2 = 11:15)
updateDT <- data.table(key_col = letters[4:7], value_col_1 = 11:14, value_col_2 = 21:24, value_col_3 = 31:34)
key_column <- "key_col"
value_columns <- setdiff(c(names(DT), names(updateDT)), key_column)

resultDT <- rbindlist(list(old = DT, new = updateDT), use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE, idcol = "origin")[, key_count := .N, by = key_column]
resultDT <- resultDT[key_count == 1L | key_count > 1L & origin == 'new'][, c("key_count", "origin") := NULL]
print(resultDT)

This is basically row binding the new table to the old one and removing duplicates based on the origin.
Edit: to avoid dropping data when not all of DTs column exist in updateDT we can simply add them upfront:
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(key_col = letters[1:5], value_col_1 = 1:5, value_col_2 = 11:15)
updateDT <- data.table(key_col = letters[4:7], value_col_2 = 11:14, value_col_3 = 21:24, value_col_4 = 31:34)
key_column <- "key_col"
value_columns <- setdiff(c(names(DT), names(updateDT)), key_column)

keep_columns <- c(key_column, setdiff(names(DT), names(updateDT)))
updateDT <- DT[, ..keep_columns][updateDT, on = key_column]

resultDT <- rbindlist(list(old = DT, new = updateDT), use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE, idcol = "origin")[, key_count := .N, by = key_column]
resultDT <- resultDT[key_count == 1L | key_count > 1L & origin == 'new'][, c("key_count", "origin") := NULL]
print(resultDT)

In the same manner we can use @Tobo's one-liner:
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(key_col = letters[1:5], value_col_1 = 1:5, value_col_2 = 11:15)
updateDT <- data.table(key_col = letters[4:7], value_col_2 = 11:14, value_col_3 = 21:24, value_col_4 = 31:34)
key_column <- "key_col"

keep_columns <- c(key_column, setdiff(names(DT), names(updateDT)))
updateDT <- DT[, ..keep_columns][updateDT, on = key_column]
rbind(DT[!updateDT, on = key_column], updateDT, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)


A slightly different apporach where you first update the values for already existing key_col-values, and afterwards rowbind the new key_col-values
# first update join new values for matching key_col-values
DT[updateDT, on=.(key_col), (value_columns) := mget(paste0("i.", value_columns))]
# then rowbind missing key_col-values
rbindlist(list(DT, updateDT[!key_col %in% DT$key_col,]), use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)

outputs to
   key_col value_col_1 value_col_2 value_col_3
    <char>       <int>       <int>       <int>
1:       a           1          11          NA
2:       b           2          12          NA
3:       c           3          13          NA
4:       d          11          21          31
5:       e          12          22          32
6:       f          13          23          33
7:       g          14          24          34


how would you modify your code to use the variable key_column <- "key_col" instead of hard coding key_col?
